# How does Start-Job not the same as executing my command directly?

Tags: powershell, dart

If I run `pub serve` from PS, it correctly starts listening on `8080` and I can connect from my browser.

```powershell
PS M:\Coding\Games\dart_games> pub serve
Loading source assets... (0.2s)
Serving dart_games web on http://localhost:8080
Build completed successfully
```

However, if I try to run it as a `Job`, it doesn't seem to work:

```powershell
PS M:\Coding\Games\dart_games> Start-Job { pub serve }

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
4      Job4            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             pub serve

PS M:\Coding\Games\dart_games> iwr http://localhost:8080/
iwr : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ iwr http://localhost:8080/
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:
        (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
        WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,
        Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass in the desired directory using the `-ArgumentList` parameter:

```
Start-Job {param($path) cd $path; pub serve } -Arg $pwd
```

Remember that the job is executing in a new PowerShell process so variables in the current process don't automatically show up there and built-ins like $pwd are likely to be set different.  `-ArgumentList` allows you to transfer whatever values you need to job process.

Comment: Ah, that's cleaner than what I had! :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the output using `Get-Job 4 | Receive-Job`. It said that `pubspec.yaml` was not found. This means it's running in the wrong folder!

I managed to make it work by passing the current folder in; though it's a bit clumsy. I can't find a better way :(

```
Start-Job -InputObject $pwd { CD $input; pub serve }
```

I wrapped these up slightly to make it a bit easier to use (with `pubstart` and `pubstop`)

```
Function Start-Pub
{
    Start-Job { param($path) cd $path; pub serve } -Arg $pwd
    & "M:\Apps\Dart\Dartium\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="M:\Apps\Dart\DartiumProfile" "http://localhost:8080/"
}

Function Stop-Pub
{
    Get-Job -State Running | ? Location -eq localhost | ? Command -like "*pub serve*" | Stop-Job
}

Set-Alias pubstart Start-Pub
Set-Alias pubstop Stop-Pub
```

It's not foolproof (will stop all pubs when you call `pubstop`), but good enough!